# Can Ubuntu or Windows run OS X?

Tags: windows-7, linux, macos, operating-systems

Can Ubuntu run Mac OS X?

I currently run Windows 7 – can I download and run one of the OS X programs?

Answer (score 4):

No, Ubuntu cannot run Mac OS X, neither legally nor technically. An OS can not run an OS. Your Ubuntu PC technically could, but Apple's EULA states OS X can only be installed on Apple machines.

As for running Mac programs on Windows 7, again this is a no. You can run some of them on Linux. Linux is Unix-like, and OS X is UNIX-certified, so some things can work.

Comment: Well, running an OS inside another OS is technically possible using [virtual machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine), but for OS X, there's still the legal issue.

Comment: Yes, but then its the VM software running the OS... I just went off of the original phrasing for simplicity.

Comment: I know it is convoluted, but you could run Ubuntu or Windows 7 on a Mac and run OS X inside a VM, that wouldn't break any Apple EULA... So shouldn't be the answer "yes"?

Comment: You might be able to run some command line tools, but no graphics based programs at all. The graphics stack of iOS and Windows or Ubuntu is completely different, and Apple keeps theirs _very_ close to their chest (it is a large part of what makes an Apple machine Apple, after all).

Comment: @jaume Running Windows on a Mac, and then OS X in a VM on that would still be against the license: *run up to two (2) additional copies or instances of the Apple Software within virtual operating system environments on each Mac Computer you own or control that is already running the Apple Software* – see the part about "already running" OS X.

Comment: @slhck Thanks for pointing that out. Interestingly, the German version doesn't mention that restriction (*Zum Installieren (...) von bis zu 2 zusätzlichen Kopien (...) der Apple Software innerhalb virtueller Betriebssystemumgebungen auf jedem Mac Computer, dessen Eigentümer Sie sind*), although, as stated later (http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/OSX1082.pdf): *Any translation (...) is done for local requirements and in the event of a dispute between the English and any non-English versions, the English version of this License shall govern, to the extent not prohibited by local law (...).*